# Gap Between Rows in Material React Table

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table, material-react-table

I have problem with collapsible table in react, when the table in collapsed mode it has gap between row. How to remove the gap?

I am using [Material-React-Table](https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/examples/advanced)

[image]

I want it to be like this

[image]

CollapsibleTableMain

```
 <div>
  <MaterialReactTable
    columns={columns}
    data={data}
    renderDetailPanel={({ row }) => (
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: 'grid',
          margin: 'auto',
          gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr',
          width: '100%'
        }}
      >
        <CollapsibleTable id={row.id} />
      </Box>
    )}
    enableExpanding
  />
</div>
```

Collapsible Table

```
 <div>
  <MaterialReactTable
    columns={columns}
    data={data}
  />
</div>
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: there should be something wrong with your css

Comment: What's this `CollapsibleTable` component?

Comment: I am using Material-React-Table component
https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/examples/advanced

Comment: Found no ``CollapsibleTable`` component in the link attached , if it is custom made can you show us the code for it . most likely the issue is with it .

Comment: Have you checked if there is any conflicting CSS for table styling? Material React Table dismounts children in the detail panel, so the `CollapsibleTable` component  can't be the culprit. It may be some styling from your theme or somewhere causing this issue.

Comment: @DewaunAyers i just using component and didn't use any table styling, I had put my children panel in  my question.